# Encountered - "raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

```
import urllib2

import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib2.Request("https://adexchanger.com/searchresults/?q=digital%20marketing")

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)

for a in soup.findAll('a'):

  if 'digital marketing' in a['href']:

    print a
```

Comment: the error message says that you can not access this site

Comment: I am trying to extract links(containing the term digital marketing) from this website. Any alternate methods to approach this problem?

Comment: Although it can be accessed through browser check for headers

Answer (score 0):

The site apparently blocks the robots and bots so you have to add chrome/ Mozzila headers to act like a browser. Try the code below.

```
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
>>> req = urllib2.Request('https://adexchanger.com/searchresults/?q=digital%20marketing', None, headers)
>>> urllib2.urlopen(req)
<addinfourl at 140245639765816 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f8d7b865250>>
```

Comment: Tried. This was the output - KeyError: 'href'

Comment: you are trying to access href attribute which does not exist. I suggest that open the webpage in the browser and inspect the elements then try to scrape using right attributes. You are not getting 403 error now right?

Comment: I didn't get the 403 error. Shall inspect the elements well. Thanks!